# Autotools Setup for Static and Shared Libraries

Tags: makefile, autotools

We have a large code base that I'm converting to autotools to help target multiple platforms / configurations. Basically, we have:

```
|-- configure.ac
|-- Makefile.am
|-- dependency1
|   `-- Makefile.am
|-- dependency2
|   `-- Makefile.am
`-- dependency3
    `-- Makefile.am
```

The dependency folders are common across many projects, so The `Makefile.am` files create `libdependencyX.la` files. In the root `Makefile.am`, I then use `LIBADD` to combine everything to create a final shared library. This all works create.

We have the need to create both shared and static versions of our library. How would I go about this? All of the dependencies just use `LTLIBRARIES` to make everything.

The original solution was just a giant Makefile that created a series of `.o` files and then building the resulting `.so` or `.a` in the end.

**Update 2015-03-11**

The issue I'm having is that I can get static or shared, but not both. The root `Makefile.am` looks like this for the final library.

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libroot.la
libroot_la_SOURCES = root.c
libroot_la_LIBADD = dependency1/libdependency1.la \
                    dependency2/libdependency2.la \
                    dependency3/libdependency3.la
libroot_la_LDFLAGS = -shared
```

Switching the `-shared` to `-static` gives me the `.a`, but how can I get both? `--enable-shared / --enable-static` doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/A-Library.html ?

Comment: Why not just `--enable-static` with `./configure`? Or build both by default with: [`LT_INIT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#LT_005fINIT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my issue is with the `libretto_la_LDFLAGS` line. Leaving that out and using `make install` gives both the .a and .so files in the prefix specified.